# php - passing an operator to a function

Tags: php

Is it possible to pass an operator to a function? Like this:

```
function operation($a, $b, $operator = +) {
    return $a ($operator) $b;
}
```

I know I could do this by passing $operator as a string and use `switch { case '+':... }`. But I was just curious.

Comment: Watch this lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to overload operators in php, but there is a workaround. You could e.g. pass the functions add, sub, mul and etc.

```
function add($a, $b) { return $a+$b; }
function sub($a, $b) { return $a-$b; }
function mul($a, $b) { return $a*$b; }
```

And then you function would be something like:

```
function operation($a, $b, $operator = add) {
    return $operator($a, $b);
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is interesting. But I don't see much a difference between this and `switch case` method.

Comment: Well, in a sense there is not much difference between any method that works. However, I would argue that the presented code would be cleaner than any method based on string operations or a switch case method. Please, post your switch case method. It would be interesting to compare.

Comment: I got my answer. I was looking for "It's not possible to overload operators". Alternative solutions are different issues. But it would be cool if we could overload operators, as C# does. Assume you want to operate on complex numbers or any other custom classes.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using eval function as

```
function calculate($a,$b,$operator)
{

    eval("echo $a $operator $b ;");
}

calculate(5,6,"*");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try, You cannot able to pass the operators in functions, YOU CAN USE FUNCTION NAME LIKE ADDITION, SUBTRACTION, MULTIPLICATION ... etc,

```
function operation($a, $b, $operator ='ADDITION') {

     $operator($a, $b);
}

 function ADDITION($a, $b){
       return $a + $b;
 }
```

Comment: He specifically said he knows you can use a switch, he was interested if there's a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I know you specifically mention not using a switch statement here, but I think it's important to show how this could be set up using switch statements as in my opinion it is the easiest, safest, and most convenient way to do this.

```
function calculate($a, $b, $operator) {
    switch($operator) {
        case "+":
            return $a+$b;
        case "-":
            return $a-$b;
        case "*":
            return $a*$b;
        case "/":
            return $a/$b;
        default:
            //handle unrecognized operators
    }
    return false;
}
```